# How to get the quantity of the same part in assembly using VBA macro

Tags: vba, solidworksapi

I am trying to get the quantity of the same parts in assembly using VBA macro. I used the following code in assembly: `qty = swComp.ComponentOccurrences.Count`

But the error alert is displayed that the object doesn't support this method or property.

What is the suitable method or property and is there any other way to get this value?

My purpose is to get the quantity of the same parts in assembly when I know the name of part. I want to know about this more specifically.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It would help to see more of your code, particularly what is `swComp` declared as

Comment: Please provide more information about your code. The API doesn't have a `ComponentOccurrences` documented for the `IComponent2` interface.

Comment: Could it be helpful if you make bill of materials table and then obtain the number from there? There's an example: Get Components in Each BOM Table Row Example (VBA)